# Magnetism of Copper

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Why is Copper considered non-magnetic? Previously I learnt that Copper is used in electric generators and motors. If the coil of copper Is made to spin by some magnetic field then shouldn't copper be magnetic? Furthermore, at the atomic level what makes copper non magnetic?

Comment: This may help - [MAGNETS: How Do They Work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM)

Answer (score 3):

Copper is nonmagnetic because a solid chunk of it is not attracted by a (ferro)magnet nearby.

When electric current flows through a piece of copper wire, the current produces a magnetic field which surrounds the wire and can be made to behave just like a permanent magnet by coiling up the wire into a cylinder. But when you stop the current flow, the magnetic field goes away and the copper coil goes back to being nonmagnetic.

Similarly, if you shake a magnet near a coil of copper wire, a current is induced to flow in the coil, even though the copper in the coil is itself nonmagnetic. Similarly, when you stop shaking the magnet, the current in the copper coil stops flowing.

whether a chunk of material is ferromagnetic or not depends on whether or not its atoms possess unpaired electron spins. The more unpaired spins, the stronger a magnet you can make out of it. This is true because the unpaired spin of an electron orbiting a nucleus itself acts like a tiny magnet.

Answer (score 1):

Magnetism is not limited to ferromagnetism.

Elemental copper is non-magnetic because its external electronic configuration is 3d104s1. Hence, the five 3d-orbitals are fully occupied by 10 electrons; each 3d orbital is occupied by a couple of paired electrons (electrons with opposite spins). Hence copper is diamagnetic.

Also in Cu+ (external electronic configuration: 3d10) all the 10 3d-electrons are paired.

In Cu+2 (external electronic configuration: 3d9) there are 9 electrons in 5 d-orbitals; so you have an unpaired electron in a d-orbital. Compounds with Cu2+ can thus exhibit magnetic ordering (for example antiferromagnetic ordering).

Comment: actually copper is *diamagnetic* with $\chi \approx -10^{-5}$, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism

Comment: sorry, you're right, I was thinking to another thing while I'm writing, I'll soon correct